# In directive $setValidity does not working

Tags: angularjs

```
<form ng-app="form-example" name="form" class="row form-horizontal" novalidate>
 <div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email || {{form.email.$error}}</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" password-validate required>
    <div class="input-help">
      <h4>Invalid Email</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</form>

var app = angular.module('form-example', []);

app.directive('passwordValidate', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require : 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element) {

      var modelController = element.find('input').controller('ngModel');

       modelController.$setValidity('myrequired', true);



    }
  }

});
```

See in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pmKpG/402/

I'm trying to push my custom validity from directive to view but it does not rendering the ouput please guide

I can see in html  {{form.email.$error}} does not showing the myrequired object as true

Answer (score 0):

You can access ngModel controller like this, since you set `require: 'ngModel'` :

```
app.directive('passwordValidate', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require : 'ngModel',
    controller: function(scope, ngModelCtrl) {
        ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('myrequired', true);
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
    }
}
});
```